# Calculating the time taken to complete the overlay display in map?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, overlay

Currently, I am able to calculate the server response time by logging the difference of current date to initialize the map with the time when layers is added. But this gives me server response time. My POI is to calculate time taken when all WMS layers are loaded successfully(let's say render time) for certain bounding box.Is there any way I can find the  render time using javascript after the `addlayer` event is successfully executed for all layers?

Comment: use fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ will give you your response time and network speeds etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I used the fiddler2 tool, but what I am interested is to find the response time in mobile device without using any emulator. I also tried to get the response time from tomcat access log using %D format which seems reasonable also for mobile device. If anybody have some better idea, It would be great to know.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the workaround for my question. I used OpenLayers register event. And displayed the time it took after the layer is fully loaded in client side.